# PerformanceCounter and remote machine

Tags: c#, remote-access, performancecounter

I'm trying watch cpu performance on remote machine with `System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter` class.
The local machine is Win7, the remote machine is Win Server 2008 Web Edition. Computers are not in workgroup and/or domain.

If I create performance counter for remote machine `new PerformanceCounter("processor", "% Processor Time", "_Total", machineName);` I get the "Access is denied" exception.

I tried the [Impersonation Sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/library/w070t6ka.aspx), but I can not logon to user at the remote machine.

How can I get performance data from remote machine?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you watch these counters remotely with perfmon? If not, get that working first. "can not logon to user at the remote machine" — need details to say anything.

Comment: Perfmon works. The error of "Logon" method is "bad username or password". But it is irelevant, because I found, the "Logon" method is only for local logon, not for remote. So use it in this scenario was totaly wrong.

Answer (score 4):

I know this question is very old but I just came across the same problem and wanted to share my solution.  What that error is basically saying is that the windows credentials of the user trying to access the remote machine are not a member of the "Performance Monitor Users" Group.  Adding your user to this group should fix the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS` logon type instead of `LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE`.

Comment: Thanks, it works for Logon function (+1)! But the PerformanceCounter constructor still throws the same exception :(

Comment: Then you're probably not passing in the correct credentials (`LogonUser (NEW_CREDENTIALS)` does not check them). What are you passing for domain name? You need to pass the name of the remote computer if the user account you're impersonating is not a domain account.

Comment: The call loks like: LogonUser("RemoteUserName", "RemoteMachineName", "RemoteUserPassword", LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, out logonHandle). But now I tried pass the wrong password, but the result was success :-O.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the State Service will only allow local-to-machine connections. To allow remote connections you’ll have to set the HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\aspnet_state\Parameters\AllowRemoteConnection key to a value of ‘1’. After changing the AllowRemoveConnection key value, you’ll have to restart the State Service service for the change to take effect. Also make sure your firewall allows connectivity to the State Service port (TCP 42424 by default).